# Sqlsrv dll does not properly load on IIS

Tags: php, php-7, sqlsrv, php-7.3

I am using **PHP 7.3** and trying to run `sqlsrv` but I cannot get my PHP environment to load `sqlsrv`. I look at the `phpinfo` and the extension does not show up. These are the steps I have taken.

1. Through the Web Platform Installer, I have installed PHP 7.3 for IIS, the SQL Server Driver, and the Windows Cache Extension.
2. I have put `php_sqlsrv_73_nts_x64.dll` in the extension directory.
3. I have verified my `php.ini` configurations.
4. Downloaded and installed the latest Microsoft ODBC driver.

Comment: What is your website being hosted through? What OS is your server? I also had a lot of issues trying to get SQL server working and the internet wasn't very helpful so I'll try my best to help you!

Comment: I am running on windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the bug. Turns out I was had installed the SQL Server Driver for IIS when I really needed the SQL Server Driver for IIS Express.

Comment: Nice! Glad you found out what the issue was :)